# How to calculate A in sin Ax if sin x° = sin Ax?

Tags: trigonometry

if sin x° = sin ax, is a 180/pi or pi/270, or 270/pi, or pi/180.

How do I calculate the value of a?

Arun

Comment: The value of $a$ would depend on $x$. If $\sin(x) = \sin(ax)$ for all $x$, then $a=1$.

Comment: 1 is not any of the choices given.  The choices give are  180/pi or pi/270, or 270/pi, or pi/180.

Comment: Is one of the arguments supposed to be in degrees while the other one is in radians?

Comment: That is not specified in the question.

Comment: Let's assume that x is in degrees.

Comment: @Indu If $x$ is in the same units on both sides, then $a$ _must_ be $1$. If one side is supposed to be degrees, and the other side radians, then the fraction $\pi/180$ will start to pop up in some form or another, depending on which side is degrees and which is radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the choices is actually $\dfrac{180^\circ}{\pi}$ or $\dfrac{\pi}{180^\circ}$ and you just failed to type the degree sign, then that is just a roundabout way of writing $1$, which is the correct answer.

(Note that the symbol ${}^{\circ}$ means to multiply by $\pi/180$).

Comment: In GeoGebra, the symbol $^\circ$ is actually coded as the constant $\pi/180$. I thought that was very cool when I first realized it.

Answer (score 0):

If argument of sinx is in degree and argument of sin ax is in radian then a=$\pi$/180

If Argument of sinx is in radian and argument of sin ax is in degree then a=180/$\pi$